# Como melhorar a performance de um foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, desempenho

Estou consumindo um `webservice`, que tem no mínimo `5557` registros.

O problema é após consumir. Tenho que adicionar no meu banco de dados os registros, e para isso, tenho que fazer um `foreach`, o que acaba atrapalhando um pouquinho a performance, demorando em média de 5 minutos.

Como faço pra melhorar?

```
var tb_municipio_ws = _ServiceReaderClient.MunicipioListar();

if (tb_municipio_ws.Items != null || tb_municipio_ws.Item != null)
{
    foreach (var item in tb_municipio_ws.Items)
    {
        var tbMunicipios = new TB_MUNICIPIOS
        {
            MUN_ID = item.MunId,
            /*
            ....
            */
        };
        _context.TB_MUNICIPIOS.Add(tbMunicipios);
    }
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Aí não tem muito o que fazer. Provavelmente dá para fazer algo no `MunicipioListar`.

Comment: Foi o que eu pensei, @bigown, mas não posso mexer nesse método.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente a causa da lentidão não é apenas a chamada ao webservice, pois mesmo com os dados disponíveis localmente o Entity Framework continuaria a fazer a checagem de mudanças (DetectChanges) pra cada registro incluído. Quanto mais registros, mais lenta se torna essa checagem.

Tente desligar o AutoDetectChanges setando o atributo `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` para `false`, assim:

```
_context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

if (tb_municipio_ws.Items != null || tb_municipio_ws.Item != null)
{
    foreach (var item in tb_municipio_ws.Items)
    {
        var tbMunicipios = new TB_MUNICIPIOS
        {
            MUN_ID = item.MunId,
            /*
            ....
            */
        };
        _context.TB_MUNICIPIOS.Add(tbMunicipios);
    }
}
_context.SaveChanges();

_context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```